# How does ORM fetch data from a Database

Tags: mysql, database-design, entity-relationship

My Question is Two fold both related to Each other

I am Designing a Database, and I am stuck on a design flaw, previously I had followed Star and snowflake schema for designing the database, but i wasn't able to use the efficiently

[Database Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKXow.png)

Note : this is just an example and i am using this as a reference in my database design, I know their can exist more than one passport

In the Database in the image there are two options , Option A and Option B , but the tables and the relations are the same only the foreign key is different

In Option B the the main (referred as library in snowflake schema) contains the foreign keys of both the address and the passport table

whereas in option A, address and passport contains the foreign key(i.e Customer ID) of the customer table

So how does the ORM Read/Write data from these related tables and according to long term use and to cause less error which is the best design option

OPTION A or OPTION B = Which?

Answer (score 1):

OPTION A, I say,  but with a key modification.

Why?

Think about this from an entity-relationship point of view.

You have Customers.  Good  choice of entity.

Each Customer may have zero or more Passports. Most Customers will have none or one, but a few might have more than one.  So Customer :: Passport   One :: Many is good.

As for Addresses:  I've handled a bunch of these sorts of databases in the wild.

A customer may have zero or more Addresses.  Most (all?) customer have at least one Address (one "contact information" entity), and many have several.   Customer :: Address  One :: Many makes a lot  of sense.

What **does not make sense in the real world** is this: multiple Customers sharing a single Address. You should probably not use a Many :: Many relationship between Customers and Addresses. Why not?  What if a Customer changes her Address? If several Customers share the same Address you'll change the address for all of them. That is a strange operation. Or you'll have to program some kind of copy-and-change scheme for changing addresses.  That's a pain in the xxx neck and easy to get wrong when you program it. Ask me how I know!

OPTION B is denormalized. You have the customer's first address embedded in the customer entity. Don't do that.

You might want a constraint requiring a customer to have one or more addresses, not zero or more addresses.  That makes sense. But MySQL's foreign key constraint system isn't sophisticated enough to enforce that constraint. So what? Just program it correctly. Don't rely on your DBMS to enforce that. Just make it a rule.

Or switch to a DBMS that can enforce it.

Comment: Essentially I realized,what I was asking was how to determine parent table and child table, relationships are not my problem i understand that, again as i mentioned above that this was just an example, what i want to know is how to determine parent&child table,as in optionA customer is the parent of both the tables (at a time) and in optionB both tables(at a time) are the parent of the customer table, I have tried googling this but i cannot find anything, aren't there certain rules or criteria a table should follow to be labeled as a child or a parent, as both are possible but which is correct

Comment: from your answer i get a brief idea that Option B is wrong bu does that apply to all, and would you mind taking a look at my DB design model @O.Jones

Comment: @Fiona: there is **no** generally applicable database design because the database design is determined by your business requirements. O Jones suggested Option A because that makes sense for customer - passport - address entities. Option B is a common model for a multi-table class inheritance implementation, like customer - business customer - private customer. You have to choose the model that fits your particular use case, we cannot tell you which one is better without the relevant domain knowledge.